# RxJava : How to wait for a value to be initialized by a previous subscription?

Tags: android, rx-java

I have a class variable that is initialized be a network call.

A getter-like method is responsible for returning the value if initialized, or **waiting** the value to be initialized if the network call hasn't returned yet.

How to implement this with RxJava ?

Another solution is that instead of **waiting**, I could simply create a new network call in case the value is still not initialized, like so:

```
private String value;

public Observable<String> getValue() {
    if (value != null) {
        return Observable.just(value);
    }

    return getValueRemotely();
}

private Observable<String> getValueRemotely() {
    ...
}
```

but I would like to avoid multiple network calls to be done.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's actually a good use-case for `AsyncSubject`.

```
private AsyncSubject<String> value = AsyncSubject.create();

public Observable<String> getValue() {
    value.asObservable();
}
```

And in `getValueRemotely()` you have to ensure the calls to `onNext()` and `onComplete()` on `value`.

```
value.onNext(valueString);
value.onCommpleted();
```

An `AsyncSubject` observable emits one item only if it was completed.

Comment: I know its old question but.... @tynn Any chances to receive same implementation for rxJava2 ? I do not fully understand, how did you call getValueRemotely() ?

Comment: It depends. You would call it once. Somehow. But you might be able to also have the call when creating the subject (maybe lazily).

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR - wrap your variable into Observable:

```
Observable<String> value = Observable
    .defer(() -> Observable.just(getValueRemotely()))
    .cacheWithInitialCapacity(1);
```

... and then use it:

```
value.subscribe(v -> /*use value received from net*/);
```

Background: RxJava is callback-based. So, when you want to get something from your observable, you don't say 'return observable.get()' - instead, you're providing a callback that will receive observable's contents. Maybe. When there will be content, actually.

It takes some mental efforts to wrap your head around the concept. With RxJava, you're rarely type 'return' keyword, you pass callbacks instead. This can feel weird at first, but in some cases callback is better than 'return'.

For example, you can ask some component to notify you about some event. In plain Java, you'll probably have to block your thread on some lock. Or you can defer sending network request until the response is really needed: the moment of arising need is the moment when there's callback ready to accept the response.

Comment: I think this solution will aways give me the delay of the network call. The mecanism I wanted was that there is no delay for returning the value if the variable has already been initialized, otherwhise just wait for the value to be initialized

Comment: Ok, just add `.cacheWithInitialCapacity(1)`. I've updated the answer.(http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#cacheWithInitialCapacity(int))

Comment: You may also need to add `.take(1)`, to ensure that your subscriber gets 'onCompleted'